# Multibinding Error

Tags: c#, wpf, multibinding

I posted my question before:
[Multi-Forms Binding data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129879/multi-forms-binding-data)

I solved it by building Converter.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Test_MultiBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="621"
        xmlns:c="clr-namespace:Test_MultiBinding">
    <Window.Resources>
        <c:myConverter x:Key="TestConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" Height="269" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="376,22,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="211" >
            <TextBox.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TestConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName="textBox2" Path="Text"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="textBox3" Path="Text"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="textBox4" Path="Text"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="textBox5" Path="Text"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="textBox6" Path="Text"/>
                </MultiBinding>
             </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
        <TextBox Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,24,0,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="222"/>
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,22,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
        <TextBox Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,70,0,0" Name="textBox3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="222" />
        <TextBox Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,116,0,0" Name="textBox4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="222" />
        <TextBox Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,162,0,0" Name="textBox5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="222" />
        <TextBox Height="91" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,208,0,0" Name="textBox6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="222" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow:

```
namespace Test_MultiBinding
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ......
    }
    [ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(string))]
    public class myConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public Object Convert(object[] value, Type targettype, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultreinfo)
        {
            return str1 + value[0].ToString() + str2 + value[1].ToString() + str3 + value[2].ToString() + str4 + value[3].ToString() + str5 + value[4].ToString() + str6;
        }

        public Object ConvertBack(object value, Type targettype, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultreinfo)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

}
```

In which str1,2,3,... are string. When I run it, I got error:

```
An object of the type "Test_MultiBinding.myConverter" cannot be applied to a property that expects the type "System.Windows.Data.IMultiValueConverter"
```

Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) you have to implement the [IMultiValueConverter Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx) instead of `IValueConverter`.

```
public class myConverter : IMultiValueConverter
```

Comment: Ok I edited it and run again, I got this error: Test_MultiBinding.myConverter' does not implement interface member 'System.Windows.Data.IMultiValueConverter.ConvertBack(object, System.Type[], object, System.Globalization.CultureInfo)'

Comment: If you're converting back, you'll need to implement the ConvertBack portion, too.

Comment: @user2627651 Of course. You have to implement the members. The signature of `Convert` and `ConvertBack` is not the same like in IValueConverter. See the sample in the link.

Comment: @user2627651 It is only `Object[] ConvertBack` instead of `Object ConvertBack`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And If I don't need ConvertBack? I mean I want OneWay binding. I tried it in XAML: Mode="OneWay" but I still have to ConvertBack

Comment: If you don't want TwoWayBinding I would use TextBlocks instead of TextBoxes. But I'm not sure if it is enough to make all bindings OneWay.

Comment: OK! I will try. One problem, when i run it, class myConverter run first, How I make class Mainwindow run first

Comment: Please ask a separate question for this because I can't say in a quick way and it is another issue too.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MultiStringConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string result = "";

        foreach(object value in values)
            result += value.ToString();

        return result;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```